# How to stop the insertion of default date format 1900-01-01 in SQL Server when user input is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, date-format

I have an input field in my application,which accepts date through date picker. Sometimes users do not select any date and they may submit blank (client requirement) as it's not a mandatory field.

Once after blank submission the data which is stored into the SQL Server 2008 database is '1900-01-01'. Instead I need the data to be stored as 'NULL' or 'empty' or '0000-00-00' but not any other valid date format.

If the `request.getparameter()` is empty, I tried to insert '0000-00-00'. But it is stopping the insertion.

My aim is to insert either 'NULL' or '-' or '0000-00-00' when the user is submitting the blank field. Instead of '1900-01-01'.

Comment: Do you have a `DEFAULT` constraint on the column?

Comment: I'd better leave it to app. Tweak the app to assign DBNull value to the db command parameter when a blank submission is detected.

Comment: The issue here is the application code - which OP never tags or shows. While the nullif approach works, it is a kludge. It is not proper application code because of the assumptions. Imagine that a default constraint is applied to this column at a later date. Now the app code must be fixed to achieve the goal of applying the default when the user does not provide a value.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, SQL Server interprets a "blank" (i.e. empty string) as a date with the value of 1900-01-01.  So when you write:

```
insert into t (datecol)
    values ('');
```

This is basically compiled into:

```
insert into t (datecol)
    values ('1900-01-01');
```

What can you do?  The most obvious is to not insert blank values.  You want to insert `NULL`, so insert `NULL`.  In this case, you can use `NULLIF()`:

```
insert into t (datecol)
    values (nullif('', ''));
```

That will turn the input into an appropriate value.

A second option is to reject such values using a check constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_datecol
    check (date >= '1950-01-01');
```

That is, dates are within some acceptable range.

A third option would be to add a trigger to convert `'1900-01-01'` to a `NULL` value when seen on input.

And a fourth option would be to allow such values but to use a computed column for reference purposes:

```
alter table t add datecol_good as ( nullif(datecol, '1900-01-01'));
```

All of these options assume that `'1900-01-01'` is not a valid date that you would want in your data.

Comment: thanks a lot    "insert into  (datecol)
    values (nullif('', ''));"   is working.